# github workflow to install chromedriver based on chrome version

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, github-actions

Does anyone know how I can create a workflow that will install the selenium chromedriver that works with the version of chrome on the build or even install a version of chrome and then the chromedriver? I am totally stuck and no amount of AI is helping

Comment: Don't they match up already? On which machine image? What versions don't work for you? And what have you tried?

Comment: sorted..somehow the runner had chrome in a different location..anyway, working now

Comment: That's great to read. If you'd  that and some more of the clarifications to your question by editing it, I'm sure this will help future users. I also added the clarifications I could find as an answer, my guess was you're on an Ubuntu runner managed by Microsoft for their Github offering.

Answer (score 1):

The machine image should ship with a version of the two compatible to each other. That is their version should normally match:

```bash
$ "CHROME_BIN" --version ; "$CHROMEWEBDRIVER/chromedriver --version"
Google Chrome 114.0.5735.90
ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386b...ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052})
```

When the versions mismatch, the locations should be verified as the system is purposefully provisioned to have a working setup.

As [Johan Grobler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7266868/johan-grobler) responded in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409431/github-workflow-to-install-chromedriver-based-on-chrome-version?noredirect=1#comment134769386_76409431):

> sorted..somehow the runner had chrome in a different location..anyway, working now

Environment parameters can help with that, more details in the rest of the answer.

---

### Microsoft Github Actions Google Chrome and Chromedriver Environment Parameters

#### `CHROMEWEBDRIVER`

Path to the directory of the chromedriver. For example `/usr/local/share/chrome_driver`.

To obtain the path to the binary executable, append `chromedriver` as a path component.

Example obtaining the **version of the ChromeDriver**:

```bash
$ "$CHROMEWEBDRIVER/chromedriver --version"
ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386b...ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052})
```

#### `CHROME_BIN`

Path to the file of the Google Chrome executable binary. For example `/usr/bin/google-chrome`.

On the Ubuntu runner it is a symbolic link that is managed by [`update-alternatives(1)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html).

Example `update-alternatives` invocation for information about the ***alternatives* Google Chrome version in use**:

```
$ update-alternatives --skip-auto --config google-chrome
google-chrome - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
  link currently points to /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
  link google-chrome is /usr/bin/google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable - priority 200
```

---

*(For runner version 2.304.0 / ubuntu-20.04 version 20230604.1 ([Included Software](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/ubuntu20/20230604.1/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md)).)*